# elasticsearch query string analyzer for different fields with different analyzers

Tags: elasticsearch

When performing a query on multiple fields which have different analyzers (stem, ngram, etc..), does elasticsearch perform specific analyzing on the query string for each field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it does, unless you specify an analyzer within your query. The [query_string](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query.html) query gets translated to a bool or a dismax query depending on the `use_dis_max` parameter within your query. A different query will be generated for each field, and the `search_analyzer` related to each specific field will be used to analyze the query.