# How many search analyzers can be used on a field?

Tags: elasticsearch

Am I right in thinking you can **only** use 1 `search analyzer` on a field?

For example say I have a field `title` with a `multi-field` of `special_title`, is it possible for me to give `title` a specific `search_analyzer1` and `special_title` another specific `search_analyzer2`? Here is a mapping to illustrate what I mean:

```
{
    "title": {
        "analyzer": "standard",
        "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer1",
        "type": "string",
        "fields": {
            "special_title": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "analyzed",
                "analyzer": "standard",
                "search_analyzer": "search_analyzer2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

It seems it isn't possible, here's a gist to prove it:

```
        PUT /my_index
        {
          "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                 "char_filter":{
                      "hyphen":{
                    "type": "pattern_replace",
                    "pattern": "[-]",
                        "replacement": ""
                 },
                      "space":{
                    "type": "pattern_replace",
                    "pattern": " ",
                        "replacement": ""
                 }      
                   },
              "analyzer": {
                 "merge":{
                    "type":"custom",
                    "tokenizer":"standard",
                    "filter": [
                      "lowercase"
                    ],
                    "char_filter": ["hyphen", "space", "html_strip"]
                  }
              }
            }
          },
          "mappings": {
            "my_type": {
              "properties": {
                "title": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "analyzer": "standard", 
                  "search_analyzer": "standard",
                  "fields": {
                    "title_merge" : {
                      "type": "string",
                       "analyzer": "standard", 
                      "search_analyzer": "merge"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }

        delete my_index

        PUT my_index/my_type/1
        {
          "title": "antiemetics" 
        }

        GET my_index/_search
        {
            "query": { 
                            "query_string" : {
                                "fields" : ["title", "title_merge"],
                                "default_operator": "AND", 
                                "query" :"anti emetics",
                                "use_dis_max" : true
                            }
                        }
        }
```

The query returns 0 results, I was hoping "anti emetics" would get passed to the `merge` search analyzer and that would then tokenize the query to `antiemetics` so that it could match on the token in the index. So looks like it's not possible which is quite odd and disappointing.

### Update 2

I am able to get the merge analyzer to kick in as expected with a match query but not with a query_string and I can't expect uses to enter a term with quotes if it's a hyphenated term they are looking for.

```
    GET my_index/_search
    {
        "query": { 
          "match": {
            "title.title_merge": "anti emetics"
          }
         }
    }
```

Comment: What version of ES you are using?

Comment: @SloanAhrens Of course I tried it, otherwise I wouldn't have posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is possible to give each field its own `search_analyzer`

For query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "title one"
    }
  }
}
```

In this case `search_analyzer1` will be applied to "title one" and for

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title.special_title": "title two"
    }
  }
}
```

this will be `analyzed` with `search_analyzer2`

**EDIT 1**

There are couple of issues with your query.

1) you should be accessing field `title_merge` with `title.title_merge`

2) I think what you are looking for is **exact** match considering your analyzer setup. Your current query is looking for two separate tokens *anti* **AND** *emetics*

You need to use **double quotes** to get expected results. From the [Docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax)

> The query string is parsed into a series of terms and operators. A
>   term can be a single word — quick or brown — or a phrase, surrounded
>   by double quotes — "quick brown" — which searches for all the words in
>   the phrase, in the same order.

I think this query will work

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "title*"
      ],
      "query": "\"anti emetics\"",
      "use_dis_max": true
    }
  }
}
```

Now ES will consider `anti emetics` as phrase and it will merge into `antiemetics` because of `space` `char_filter` and you will get expected results.

Does this help?

Comment: could you please tell what version of ES you are using?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, it's 2.0

Comment: I have updated my answer, please have a look, did it work?

Comment: Thank you so much for this, re the documentation reference that is very interesting! Also you are correct about point 1. However what I don't understand though is why is it necessary to put it in quotes, I don't seem to have to do this for a normal match query, please see update 2.

Comment: The reason my query is looking for two seperate tokens is because I'm tokenising on hyphens but I also want the user to be able to perform a query that has two separate terms that can be merged to find potential matches in the index (where the original content is missing a hyphen)

Comment: as I said, query string is looking for `anti` or `emetics` and finds none because what you have inside the index is `antiemetics`, it is internally translated into **bool** query. [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658293/elasticsearch-query-string-analyzer-for-different-fields-with-different-analyzer) obviously match query will work because query gets `analyzed` and turns into `antiemetics` and returns result. I hope this clears the confusion. pls do not hesitate to ask more question if it is still not clear.

Comment: also there is no need for users to type quotes, you could do that while sending the query to ES, if you have more requirements, you could use `multimatch` query